# Does Eclipse have an editor/viewer for java serialized files?

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization, object, viewer

I'm serializing my objects with `ObjectOutputStream(FileOutputStream(File))` and deserializing them with the analogous `InputStreams`. Is there a way to look inside of these serialized files (in eclipse preferably), so I can check, if all necessary attributes were written?

edit: google search was negative

Comment: I think you mean the other way around.

Comment: Know this is so stupid but... double click in Eclipse (at least Luna and .ser as extension) show the object using default toString()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write some tests (using Eclipse's built-in JUnit support).

The only way to "look inside" these files is to use `ObjectInputStream(FileInputStream(File))`, unless you're a bytecode guru and use a hex editor. If you actually have some testing, there is no need to "look inside" anything.

Comment: +1 For insisting that testing is the right way to verify serialization.

Comment: Thank you, I tended to "do" tests, instead of writing them. Your solution gives me motivation to actually write a test ;)

Comment: Tests are great, but don't help when debugging a production issue in a program you inherited.

Comment: @j_random_hacker oh yes they do

Answer (score 4):

While this isn't a full fledged editor, Eamonn McManus has written a transcoder which deciphers a serialized blob into a human readable form.  http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2007/06/12/disassembling-serialized-java-objects

If binary compatibility and performance are considerations, this would be a good time to look into Externalizable instead of Serializable.

Comment: The article has dead download link. But the source can be found at https://github.com/frohoff/serialysis.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a "free standing" answer, just an expansion of OrangeDog's answer.

*"Write some tests (using Eclipse's built-in JUnit support). "*

If you want to test serialization, then write tests that do the following:

1. Serialize one object to a file.
2. Deserialize to a different object from the same file.
3. Compair both objects to see that the deserialized object contains all of the values that were supposed to have been serialized (*i.e.* make sure that *"all necessary attributes were written"*).

Answer (score 1):

Write a class which loads the file and deserialises the object. Then use Eclipse's Debugging View to browse the object (by setting a breakpoint).

Answer (score 0):

I found [SerializationDumper](https://github.com/NickstaDB/SerializationDumper), downloaded its [v1.13 binary jar](https://github.com/NickstaDB/SerializationDumper/releases/download/1.13/SerializationDumper-v1.13.jar), and was quickly able to read a serialised file.

As you might expect from a tool that doesn't use (or require access to) the corresponding `.class` files themselves, the text output is quite arcane -- but I was able to decipher the contents of a small object containing a `String[]`, a `HashSet` and a `boolean`.