# Java - easy way to inspect structure of serialized object?

Tags: java, serialization

I have a class and I'd like to see which sub-objects occupy the most space when object from this class is serialized. Is there any nice tool/way to do it, except from looking at the code and analyzing it manually?

For example I would like the tool to say "member a occupies 20%, b 30% and member c occupies 50%".

Thanks

P.S. I found some related questions, but didn't find answer to my specific question there.

Comment: Possibly related: [Estimating Java Object Sizes with Instrumentation](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2011/12/estimating-java-object-sizes-with.html)

Comment: See my comment to #alexey28 - I am interested in the structure of the serialized object, not the structure of object in memory

Comment: There are no 'sub-objects' in java. And it is not a semantic issue. How do you count the share if two members of an object have common members themselves?

Answer (score 1):

The only relatively fast way to count the size of the object is to first write the whole object, count the usage (for example, write to a ByteArrayOutputStream) and then write each object that is referred to.

There are a couple of this to take into account:

- The ObjectOutputStream does do some caching to be able to refer to a previously written object with a simple pointer. Use the reset() method to clear this cache.
- Each new object type that is written, first has the class description. The overhead of this depends on the number of same-type objects that you are referring to.
- There is a (small, 4-byte) overhead to initialize the ObjectOutputStream.

For the description of the protocol, read [this description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html).

Comment: That's the way I thought to do it, unless I will get a better answer, this will be the way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) provides [Serialized Java Objects Viewer](http://www.dbvis.com/doc/7.0/doc/ug/editData/editData.html#mozTocId646511).

There also a `serialysis` tool mentioned at [Does Eclipse have an editor/viewer for java serialized files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4889761/does-eclipse-have-an-editor-viewer-for-java-serialized-files)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've never heard about such tool. But I think there is some relation between object size in memory and serialized object size. So you can try using a profiler: [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net), which is included in JDK or my favorite [YourKit Profiler](http://www.yourkit.com).

Comment: There is some relation but not that strong relation - class can choose to serialize some members, and discard others. This can totally change the picture...

Comment: Lets way for some other answers. If no one know such tool and you need precission measurement - you have to write your own to do it.